# Why do template classes allow member functions which cannot compile?

Tags: c++, templates

```
class P
{
};

template< typename P >
class C : public P
{
  public:
  void f()
  {
    P::f();
  }
};

int main() {
  C<P> c1;
  return 0;
}
```

Just in case my question leaves any room for misunderstanding, here is a code example. If `C` was *not* templated but inherited from `P` directly, then the sample would fail to compile because clearly function `f()` attempts to call a function on base class `P` which is non-existent.

However if `C` is templated then this is only picked up if `f()` is actually called.

I'd like to know why there is this difference. In both instances `f()` would be dead code and stripped anyway, yet the program is ill-formed in the non-template scenario.

Comment: Note that you could trigger an error by explicitly instantiating `C<P>`.

Comment: It's never compiled, so it's not being "allowed", it simply doesn't exist in anything but text form.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Actually, the program you posted is not ill-formed. While the "implicit instantiation" `C<P> c1;` instantiates all member *declarations*,

> the specialization of the member is implicitly instantiated when the specialization is referenced
>   in a context that requires the member definition to exist

[N4140, 14.7.1(2)] Since you never use `C<P>::f`, its *definition* is never needed and thus never instantiated.

This is different to an "explicit instantiation" like

```
template class C<P>;
```

which would instantiate the *definition* of all members of `C<P>` and thus result in an error.

Answer (score 8):

Because it makes sense to allow to use only the functions that are actually well formed.

Take `vector::push_back(const T&)`, that requires `T` to be copyable. But you can still use most of `vector` even if `T` is a movable non-copyable type.

Answer (score 5):

Inside the template class, identifier `P` is a template parameter typename, it *does not* refer to the `class P` defined before. So you can't say `P::f()` is not-existent, as you do not know what class will be substituted for parameter `P`.

And later, when you invoke the template to declare the `c1` variable, the function is not needed, so there is no 'dead code' – there is just a template, which has never been expanded to an actual code.

Answer (score 3):

If I write a non-template class which inherits from `P`, calling a non-existent function on that class from a member function is obviously an error as there is no use for it whatsoever.

If `C` is a template class, however, maybe that erroneous call is valid for some other `P`. Maybe that member function represents some extended functionality for types which support some given interface. `C` could be instantiated from some external library that I have no knowledge of when instantiating for `P`. As such, throwing a compiler error for an unused function in a template class which could be valid for certain types would limit the expressive power of templates. It also brings down compile-times, binary sizes, etc. because that unneeded template function doesn't need to be generated for types when it is not used.

Answer (score 2):

Variable `C<P> c1;` is not used and the `C::f()` function is never called. Compiler doesn't create body of function until it is used. This is a simple optimization which speeds up the compilation.