# Well-formed program containing an ill-formed template member function?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

In the snippet below, I'm puzzled about why the definition of `Wrapper::f() const` does not make my program ill-formed<sup>1</sup> although it calls a non-const member function of a non mutable member variable:

```
// well-formed program (???)
// build with: g++ -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic
template<class T> struct Data { void f() {} };

template<class T> struct Wrapper
{
    Data<T> _data;
    void f() const { _data.f(); } // _data.f(): non-const!
};

int main()
{
    Wrapper<void> w; // no error in instantiation point?
    (void) w;
}
```

<kbd>[demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8cd26e2129d114b5)</kbd><sup>2</sup>

On the other hand, if `Data` is a non template class<sup>3</sup>, a diagnostic is issued by my compiler:

```
// ill-formed program (as expected)
// build with: g++ -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic
struct Data { void f() {} };

template<class T> struct Wrapper
{
    Data _data;
    void f() const { _data.f(); } //error: no matching function for call to 'Data::f() const'
};

int main()
{
    Wrapper<void> w;
    (void) w;
}
```

<kbd>[demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/03742f915020763c)</kbd>

I feel like the answer will contain expressions such as "deduced context" ... but I really cannot pin down the exact part of the standard scecifying this behaviour.

**Is there a language lawyer to enlighten me on the matter?**

---

Notes:
 <sup>1)</sup> But I get an error if I try and effectively *call* `Wrapper<T>::f() const`.
 <sup>2)</sup> I've compiled with `-std=c++17` but this is not specific to C++17, hence no specific tag.
 <sup>3)</sup> In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31328843/5470596), @Baum mit Augen quotes `[N4140, 14.7.1(2)]`:

> the specialization of the member is implicitly instantiated when the specialization is referenced in a context that requires the member definition to exist

but here in the compiling snippet (#2) `void f() const { _data.f(); }` fails although its *"specialization is **never** referenced in a context that requires the member definition to exist"*.

Comment: I dont think the duplicate covers everything for this question. At least I would expect also the second version to compile according to the asnwer given on the dupe

Comment: @tobi303 True, not sure why that is tbh.

Comment: [\[temp.res\]/8](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res#8). See (8.1) in particular.

Comment: @cpplearner 8.1 is about `constexpr if`...

Comment: @YSC it is about "template **or** a substatement of a constexpr if statement within a template", though thats about all I understand. standard isnt a language I can understand :(

Comment: Welp, looks like @cpplearner is right and my answer is wrong. I forgot about that rule. Do you want to post your own answer or should I fix mine?

Comment: @tobi303 Ho yes, I've read _no valid specialization can be generated for (a template or a substatement) of a constexpr if_ instead of _no valid specialization can be generated for a template or (a substatement of a constexpr if)_; but it doesn't make sense :D my bad

Comment: relevant: [`[temp.dep]/1`](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.dep#1) and [`[temp.dep.expr]/5`](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.dep#expr-5): `_data.f()` in both snippets are _"type dependant expressions"_. Ok, then?

Comment: I got it wrong, only in snippet with templated `Data` is `_data.f()` a _type dependent expression_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Snippet #2 is *ill-formed*.

As already stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10323980/templates-compilation-gcc-vs-vs2010), the template definition of `Wrapper::f` is well-formed (thus no diagonstics are issued) as long as a valid specialization can be *generated*.

[§17.7/8 [temp.res]](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res#8) states:

> Knowing which names are type names allows the syntax of every template
>   to be checked. The program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if:
>
> - no valid specialization can be generated for a template or a substatement of a constexpr if statement within a template and the
>     template is not instantiated, or [...]

In neither of the two code snippets, `Wrapper<void>::f` is getting instantiated, because of the rules in [§17.7.1/2 [temp.inst]](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.inst#2):

> The implicit instantiation of a class template specialization causes
>   the implicit instantiation of the *declarations*, but not of the
>   definitions, [...].

(emphasizing done by me)

But now §17.7/8 kicks in: if there is no instantiation and *there can be no generated specialization* for which the template definition of `Wrapper::f` is valid (which is the case for snippet #2, as for every generated specialization `Wrapper<T>::f`, a `non-const` call inside a `const` function on a member is would be performed), the program is ill-formed and diagnostics are issued.

But because the diagnostics are not mandatory (see §17.7/8 above), the GCC can deny snippet #2 while both [VS](http://rextester.com/JTBRR73709) and [clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/tiNxQqc2aGjCHzNd) compile the same code flawlessly.

For snippet #1 however you could provide a user-defined specialization for `Data` where `Data::f` is `const` (say `Data<void>::f`). Therefore, a valid, *generated* specialization of `Wrapper::f` is possible, i.e. `Wrapper<void>::f`. So in conclusion, snippet #1 is well-formed and snippet #2 is invalid; all compilers work in a standard-conforming manner.

Comment: Reading the edit history of this answer is a truly wild ride.

Comment: @Griwes Ha XD That explains a *lot*! In its (temporary?) final form, this answer deserves upvotes though.

Comment: @YSC Don't worry, I am pretty sure now this is fine. I have to admit that reading the standard involved me in a learning process, obviously I wasn't à priori sure what the answer might be.